# how can i test custom directive in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

i'm trying to write test case for custom directives with Jasmine. Currently, I have a directive that is setup as shown here:
This is my code in fiddler
http://jsfiddle.net/aHmPV/33/

```
app.directive('focusMe', function ($timeout) {
 return {
    scope: { trigger: '=focusMe' },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('trigger', function (value) {
            if (value === true) {
                element[0].focus();

            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

My Jasmine code is in fiddler
I tried different ways to test $watch function unable to achieve it , please help

Comment: What did you try? It is much appreciated if you show some effort and then ask a question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are set $watch on `scope.trigger`, but it is passed in `focus-me`.

You can use `spyOn` to `element[0].focus` and create test for `focus-me="true"` and `focus-me="false"`:

```
describe('Directive: focusMe', function() {
    var element,
        scope;

    beforeEach(module('CommonBusInfo'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    it("should focus if focus-me is true", inject(function($compile) {
        element = angular.element('<input type="text" focus-me="true" value="chaitu">');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        spyOn(element[0], 'focus');

        scope.$digest();

        expect(element).toBeDefined();
        expect(element[0].focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

    it("should NOT focus if focus-me is falsy", inject(function($compile) {
        element = angular.element('<input type="text" focus-me="" value="chaitu">');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        spyOn(element[0], 'focus');

        scope.$digest();

        expect(element).toBeDefined();
        expect(element[0].focus).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

Comment: can you check this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879799/unit-testing-directive-with-angularjs-jasmine/32881517#32881517